# SQL Developer: find views created in the last week

Tags: sql, oracle, database-metadata

I am new to SQL and I created some views when testing something on a database at work.

Then I realized that I should remove them but I'm not sure that I dropped them all.

Where can I find a list of all(still existing) views created in the last week?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search the USER_OBJECTS to find the view created within specified duration like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM user_objects
WHERE object_type = 'VIEW'
AND created BETWEEN sysdate - 7 AND sysdate;
```

If the current user is not the owner of the view, you'll have to use ALL_OBJECTS or DBA_OBJECTS like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ALL_OBJECTS 
WHERE object_type = 'VIEW'
AND OWNER = 'SOMEUSER'
AND created BETWEEN sysdate - 7 AND sysdate;
```

Comment: I had to change the 'created_table' to 'created', but otherwise it worked! Thanks!